# How to show jQuery colorbox popup alert on the onchange event of select control in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, popup, colorbox, alert, onchange

Actually I want to show the different hidden jQuery colorbox popup on the selection of each option from the select control. In short the concerned jQuery colorbox popup should be called upon selection of concerned option. The code for hidden colorbox popups along with the jQuery code which I tried to show them is as follows:

```
    <select name="select_option">
      <option value="0">--Select Action--</option>
      <option value="1" class="delete_user" href="#deletePopContent">Delete User</option>
      <option value="2" class="disable_user" href="#disablePopContent">Disable User</option>
      <option value="3" class="update_user" href="#updatePopContent">Update Class and Section</option>
      <option value="4" class="default_user" href="#defaultPopContent">Default Password</option>
    </select>
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="deletePopContent" class="c-popup">
    <h2 class="c-popup-header">Delete USers</h2>
    <div class="c-content">         
      <h3>Are you sure to delete selected users?</h3>
      <p class="alert"><strong>You are about to perform an action which can't be undone</strong></p>
      <a href="#"class="c-btn">No</a><a href="#"class="c-btn" id="delete_url">Delete</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="disablePopContent" class="c-popup">
    <h2 class="c-popup-header">Disable Users</h2>
    <div class="c-content">         
      <h3>Are you sure to disable selected users?</h3>
      <p class="alert"><strong>You are about to perform an action which can't be undone</strong></p>
      <a href="#"class="c-btn">No</a><a href="#"class="c-btn" id="disable_url">Disable</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="updatePopContent" class="c-popup">
    <h2 class="c-popup-header">Update Users</h2>
    <div class="c-content">         
      <h3>Are you sure to update selected users?</h3>
      <p class="alert"><strong>You are about to perform an action which can't be undone</strong></p>
      <a href="#"class="c-btn">No</a><a href="#"class="c-btn" id="update_url">Update</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
  <div id="defaultPopContent" class="c-popup">
    <h2 class="c-popup-header">Change Password</h2>
    <div class="c-content">         
      <h3>Are you sure to change password?</h3>
      <p class="alert"><strong>You are about to perform an action which can't be undone</strong></p>
      <a href="#"class="c-btn">No</a><a href="#"class="c-btn" id="default_url">Delete</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()  { 
$(".delete_user").click(function(e) { 
    $(".delete_user").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});
});

$(".disable_user").click(function(e) { 
    $(".disable_user").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});

  });

$(".update_user").click(function(e) { 
    $(".update_user").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});

  });
$(".default_user").click(function(e) { 
    $(".default_user").colorbox({inline:true, width:666});

  });
});
</script>
```

I tried above code but not able to show the corresponding colorbox popup. CAn you help me in this regard please? Thanks in advance.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select[name="select_option"]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

You can do this using below code inside above change event code.

```
$($(this).attr('class').colorbox({inline:true, width:666});
```

**Complete Code**

```
$('select[name="select_option"]').change(function()
{
    var classname = $('select[name="select_option"]')
        .find(':selected').attr('class');
    $('.'+classname).colorbox({inline:true, width:666});
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGgy3/4/)

Comment: :Thanks for your help but how could I call different popup having concerned id with on the selection of corresponding option?

Comment: @PHPGeek can you share entire details in question...?

Comment: :Ok, I'll modify my question. Give me 5 minutes for modification.

Comment: :I've modified my question. If you need further details I can provide you the same.

Comment: :It's still not working. If you look at your code you are applying class attribute of select control(class attribute of select having id 'select_option') itself while calling the colorbox. I think it should be class of a option value selected. Isn't it?

Comment: :Thank you so much Dipesh for your help. Now it's working perfectly as I needed.